# I.C.E problem. dial list. s4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, phone-app

I recently found the emergency call list, which can dial a number even when the screen is locked.  I added a number from my contact list to test out how it works.  After I figured out how it worked, I went to add 4 more numbers from my contact list, but I found out I could only add 3 total numbers.  I deleted the first contact from my list that I used for testing purposes, but now I can't add another number on that spot, and also can't delete that number.  When I tap the first spot, it will dial as an unknown number.  How can I fix this?  Can I get this first number to go away so I can add another number to my emergency call list?